# Major difference in text rendering on Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, antialiasing

I'm having some major differences in the rendering of text between Chrome and Firefox. Chrome seems to apply some anti-aliasing rules to the text and shrinks it down quite a bit.

I've tried playing with -webkit-font-smoothing, letter-spacing and word-spacing but none seem to really have any effect.

See screenshots

[image: Rendering on Chrome]

Relevant CSS (computed):

```
color: #C4C4C4;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
```

[image: Rendering on Firefox]

Relevant CSS (computed):

```
font-family:    sans-serif;
font-size:  9px;
font-weight:    400;
font-style: normal;
font-size-adjust:   none
color:  #C4C4C4;
text-transform: none;
text-decoration:    none;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing:   0;
line-height:    11.0833px;
text-align: start;
vertical-align: baseline;
direction:  ltr;
```

Note that the faded text in the background is just an image.. ignore that.

I have a feeling Chrome has a css switch for anti-aliasing rules, but not sure where to look for more info.

Edit:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mHzhQ/

For the record, I'm on Ubuntu. Possibly this has an impact ..

Any tips?

Comment: did you use a CSS Reset or CSS Normalize?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this. I'm using Blueprint css which includes a reset. So yes.

Comment: make a fiddle. It will a lot easier to test it.

Comment: Checked on FF 6.0.2 and GG 14 in windows 7. See no difference. Pretty sure it is an OS situation.

Comment: I tried it on Win, Linux and Mac. On Windows there's least of a difference but on Mac and Linux it's quite noticeable. I guess I'll just have to find a font that renders mostly the same across browsers & OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different browsers use different rendering engines that (are meant to) produce different results. This is especially the case with smaller font sizes. There's generally not a whole lot you can do about it. If the difference is not intended by the browser's designers, it's also quite possible that this is a kink that has been worked out on other OSs, but not yours (Ubuntu).

(That said: have you checked your "minimum font size" in Chrome — Preferences > Under the Hood > Customize Fonts... — and Firefox — Preferences > Content?)

Answer (score 1):

"sans-serif" may result in a different font

so if you:

font-family:verdana, sans-serif;

you will see a nearly pixel-perfect result in both browsers

HTH

Comment: I did try other fonts such as Verdana, but they had the same effect. They all seem smaller and more condensed on Chrome.